# Hello, I am new to RUBY and I try to run some code in my terminal, Most of my programs runs perfect but others run and dont show anything

Tags: ruby

An example

```
require 'sinatra'

get ('/hello/') do 
    'Hello, web!'
end
```

and when I try to run it just runs and doesn't show anything

```
[Running] ruby "c:\coding\ruby visual code files\hello_web.rb"
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.213 seconds
```

Comment: What do you expect it to show? Have you installed one of the servers (e.g., webrick, puma, ...)?

Comment: I expect to show me a log message from the server for example     WEBrick: : HTTPServer#start: pid = 6742 port=4567         so I can run it on a local host. I have only installed gem sinatra

Comment: Hard to say if you're trying to run it from within VS Code. It works fine for me from either the command line or within VSCode, but I also needed to install a server (I used webrick).

Comment: I can't figure it out , but thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try adding `Sinatra::Application.run!` at the end. That is what Sinatra normally runs in an `at_exit` handler. Why it doesn't run it now for you, is quite strange. Do you have something else occuping the default port?

Comment: Assuming all else fails, run Pry or Debug hello_web.rb to see where your program is wandering off to. There's simply not enough info in your current question to debug what is most likely an issue with your environment or code you haven't posted.

Comment: I tried run and Debug in vs code and it just ran. I don't know why  my terminal exited too soon before. Thanks for the help!